# Kotlin while loop won't execute after endet

Tags: kotlin, gradle, ktor

Hey so i have zero idea what is happening. So i'm here.

Basically I have a variable called `isReady` which is been flipped in another thread.

In the main Thread there is a while loop which checks if it is been flipped and then executes code.

This only works if there is an `println` function call in the while loop. i have no idea why

*Examples*:

**WONT WORK:**

```
// is executed
while(!isReady) {}
// wont be executed
```

**WONT WORK:**

```
var a = false
// is beeing executed
while(!isReady) {
    a = isReady
}
// wont be executed
println(a)
```

**WILL WORK:**

```
// is beeing executed
while(!isReady) {
    println(isReady)
}
// is beeing executed
```

My Code:

```
Thread {
    embeddedServer(io.ktor.server.cio.CIO, restApi.server).start(wait = true)
}.start()

while (!restApi.isReady) {
    println()
}
// will work but ugly println
```

Different code but only println function works and i dont want that

Comment: Try adding the `@Volatile` annotation to `isReady` - if you're changing the value on another thread, it's possible this thread can't see the update. Multithreading is tricky like that (making it volatile forces the value to be synchronised across threads). You'd be better using coroutines if you can

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to wait until `restApi.isReady`?

Comment: If you want to determine when the server is started then you can use the `ApplicationStarted` event https://ktor.io/docs/events.html#handle-events-application

Comment: @AlekseiTirman So first, how do i close a question if the answer is in the comments? help? second: I need to wait until the rest api is ready due to internal calls for the API to keep it simpler. 3. worked for over a year with ktor and never heard about an event system. thanks :)

Comment: Does the solution with the event subscription work for you? If so I will post it as the answer.